# File browser with a ListView and back button

Tags: android, json, file, listview, explorer

I am working on a simple file explorer using android os.
I get the whole directory structure like filesize, filenames, directory name via a json object and put them in a list view. On 1) you can see, what I finally want to do.

The problem is, that the items have a complete other style like the back botton, so I may have to deal with two list views (one for the back button in every sub directory and one for the items like the 2nd variant in my picture). But having two listviews, the first one should resize in the root directory, so that it fits in the height like the version with a back button.

Do you have any ideas? I hope you unterstand, want I want.

1]: http://www.basepic.com/2014/Mar/13/97965279.png

Comment: WOuldn't it be better if you just add a button with the visibility GONE. And only make it visible on the top if you want to show the back button else just leave it hidden? Why a seperate listview for just one button?

Comment: Sometimes simple things become to complex in my mind :) Thank your for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOuldn't it be better if you just add a button with the visibility GONE. And only make it visible on the top if you want to show the back button else just leave it hidden? Why a seperate listview for just one button?